# Events are not loaded in FullCalendar MVC5 JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I am trying to display the events in my FullCalendar plugin but unfortunately something is wrong with my code.

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (HumanForceDBEntities context = new HumanForceDBEntities())
        {
            var currUser = currentUser.GetCurrUser();
            var events = context.HF_MyReport_PM.Select(x => new {
                id = x.Id,
                title = x.Description,
                start = x.StartDate.ToString(),
                end = x.EndDate.ToString(),
                ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                CurrentUser = x.CurrentUser
            }).Where(x => x.CurrentUser == currUser.Id).ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

My JS Functions

```
  function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            myEvents = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "/MyTimer/GetEvents",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (events) {
                    var MyResult = JSON.stringify(events);
                    $.each(events, function (key, entry) {
                        alert(entry.Id);
                        myEvents.push({
                            id: entry.Id,
                            title: entry.Description,
                            start: moment(entry.StartDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                            end: moment(entry.EndDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                        });
                    })
                    GenerateCalender(myEvents);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })
        }

        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            alert(events);
            var myEvents = [];
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 100,
                defaultView: 'basicWeek',
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                titleFormat: 'MMMM-YYYY',
                //timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'basicWeek'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: events,

            })
        }
```

The information from the controller seems to came empty, however when I debug the method it seems to be right.

Can somebody help me out with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing `var MyResult = JSON.stringify(events);` to `var MyResult = events;`. JSON.stringify turns your data array back into a string, so you can't process it anymore. It makes no sense to do that. (P.S. jQuery already turned the JSON string which came from the server into a usable array, because you had specified the `dataType: "json"` AJAX option

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, then you'll need to add more debugging info, such as console errors, the result of the AJAX query as shown in your network tab, and the exact JSON being supplied by your server code.

Comment: P.S. it _looks_ like your server will already produce JSON in the correct format (with "id", "title", "start" and "end" properties as required by fullCalendar. So your $.each loop doesn't seem to make sense, because it will be trying to read properties which don't exist in your objects. I would expect you can just write `success: function (events) { GenerateCalender(events); }` and it will probably work.

Comment: P.P.S. the correct spelling is `Calendar` not `Calender`

Comment: P.P.P.S. you don't need to wait for the events to be downloaded before you draw the calendar. Also, fullCalendar can dynamically fetch new events from the server for you. I suggest that you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function

Comment: It displays this error in the console: `https://localhost:44358/%22[%7B/%22id/%22:27,/%22title/%22:/%2233/%22,/%22start/%22:/%2208/07/2019/%22,/%22end/%22:/%2208/07/2019/%22,/%22ProjectId/%22:55,/%22CurrentUser/%22:9%7D]%22?start=2019-07-28&end=2019-09-08&_=1565187386848`

Comment: This on the browser: `https://localhost:44358/%22[%7B/%22id/%22:27,/%22title/%22:/%2233/%22,/%22start/%22:/%2208/07/2019/%22,/%22end/%22:/%2208/07/2019/%22,/%22ProjectId/%22:55,/%22CurrentUser/%22:9%7D]%22?start=2019-07-28&end=2019-09-08&_=1565187386848`

Comment: what displays that exactly, and when? That doesn't look like an error message so much as a badly formed URL. It appears to contain some JSON in the URL for some reason but from your code I can't see how it could have got there. Have you changed your code from what you showed above? If you expect me to debug some code, you at least need to show it. Right now I can't understand how you are getting this output, or when it would occur. It's unclear if or how this information relates to any of the suggestions I made, either. Did you attempt to implement them? if so then, again, show your new code